# instance is null after renaming project

Tags: java, oop, nullpointerexception

I'm working in IntelliJ and I attempted to rename my Project! After doing so, and renaming everything, which I believe I did correctly, I'm unable to actually start my application.

Error:

```
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:133) ~[spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-4df3c0c-03f1e37]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:326) ~[spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-4df3c0c-03f1e37]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:248) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-4df3c0c-03f1e37]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:302) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-4df3c0c-03f1e37]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:205) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-4df3c0c-03f1e37]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:544) [spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-4df3c0c-03f1e37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at me.craftblock.MochaMessages.Config.<init>(Config.java:7) ~[?:?]
    at me.craftblock.MochaMessages.MochaMessages.<init>(MochaMessages.java:18) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:76) ~[spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-4df3c0c-03f1e37]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:129) ~[spigot-latest.jar:git-Spigot-4df3c0c-03f1e37]
    ... 6 more
```

The error points to my Config class, however I'm not sure why:

```
public class Config {
    private MochaMessages instance = MochaMessages.getInstance();
    private FileConfiguration config = instance.getConfig();

    public Config() {
    }

    public String get(String node) {
        System.out.println("Fetching: " + node);
        return config.getString(node);
    }

    public void set(String node, String value) {
        config.set(node, value);
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(String node) {
        System.out.println("Fetching: " + node);
        return config.getBoolean(node);
    }

}
```

Which is being called via my MochaMessages class:
Here's the related method:

```
private static MochaMessages instance;
private Config config = new Config();
public void onEnable() {
    instance = this;
    createConfig();
    te = getTokenEnchant();
    if (!config.getBoolean("database.enabled")) {
        disablePlugin("Enable MySQL!");
    } else if (config.get("mocha.currency").equalsIgnoreCase("TokenEnchant")) {
        if (te == null) {
            disablePlugin("Unable to access TokenEnchant. Disabling Plugin!");
        }
    } else {
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MochaListener(), this);
        new MochaModel().createTable();
        new CommandHandler();
    }
}
```

I believe it's because instance is returning null even though it shouldn't be. This worked perfectly before the rename!

What's going on?

Comment: `private static MochaMessages instance;
    private MochaMessages instance = MochaMessages.getInstance();
    private FileConfiguration config = instance.getConfig();` this is bad because you expect "things" to happen in some order. Furthermore, you have two "instance"

Comment: You must restart the PC and import the same

Comment: @RC. Sorry, was actually pasted in incorrectly, I fixed the code in the question.